# what are snicaddr and snicstats in Python?

Tags: python, networking, psutil

function psutil.net_if_addrs() returns a dictionary where for each network card includes a list of objects of type snicaddr, but I have not been able to find the definition of this type.

also, function psutil.net_if_stats returns a dictionary where for each network card includes an object of type snicstats, whose definition I cannot find.

Comment: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#network or google for _psutil.net_if_addrs()_

Answer (score 1):

snicaddr and snicstats are subclasses of namedtuple and defined on _common.py of psutil (see below)

```
198 # psutil.net_if_addrs()
199 snicaddr = namedtuple('snicaddr',
200     ['family', 'address', 'netmask', 'broadcast', 'ptp'])
201 # psutil.net_if_stats()
202 snicstats = namedtuple('snicstats',
203      ['isup', 'duplex', 'speed', 'mtu', 'flags'])
```